# Pass data from child component to appcomponent without circular dependency

Tags: angular

I have divided my angular application into a number of libraries.

My app component template will look like

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Also I configured some routes like,

> /home - home component
>   /users/user - user component(as child
>   component inside user component)

Now I need to pass data from home or user component to header component.

I know this can be achieved by using a service or store.

But my issue is that header, home, user all are in different libraries because of this, 
I am getting circular dependency.

So what I am trying now is passing data from home/user to appcomponent first and then pass data from appcomponent to header
using `@Output`, `@Input` and `emitter`. But I am not able to pass data to `<router-outlet>`

Please help me to solve this situation

Comment: Have you tried using a service and accessing the data directly.

Comment: Because your `app-header` and `home` or `user` are not in `parent <-> child` relationship, you only can achive this with service or store.

Comment: @smithnblack Wont service be a better option as angular embraces services? (I agree store is good too)

Comment: I would like re-use my libraries in another application, so if one library depends on service of another library, then I cant't re-use that also there will be circular dependency warning..

Comment: Yes, for sure! `NgRx Store` would be far more for complex applications where you need to keep information in `store` to be able to access it any time and in any application, independent from sibling status of components.  Imagine Shopping Website, where you need to keep Shopping Cart Items across your whole application.

Comment: Here is pretty good example of using service: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Answer (score 0):

Your header component and home components are not connected to each other. You should try with BehaviourSubject and pass it through a service. Service should be like following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

Let's say, you have a button on your home component, you want to show this message on your components onInit method. Then call it like the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```